# How to statistically estimate weighted average with some unknown values?

Tags: statistical-inference

I am stuck in a tricky problem.  There are 32 companies. They have their own GHG emission factors and their market shares.  This is, $ X_1, X_2, ..., X_n $ and $ Y_1, Y_2, ..., Y_n $.  I am looking for its weighted mean. $\sum_{i=0}^n  \frac{X_i \times Y_i}{Y_i}$

However, I have some problem.

$ X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4 $ are known. (That is, $ X_5,..., X_n $ are unknown.)
$ Y_1, Y_2, ..., Y_n $ are known.
$ X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4 $ make up 80% of market. (It means $\sum_{i=1}^4 Y_i$ is 80%.)
$ n $ is 32.
Can I estimate weighted mean. $\sum_{i=0}^n  \frac{X_i \times Y_i}{Y_i}$?  Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean

$$
\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n  {X_i \times Y_i}}{ \sum_{i=0}^nY_i}.
$$

Assuming the $X_i$ are nonnegative, you can set the unknown ones to $0$ to find a lower bound on the average. Since they can be as large as you like, you can't estimate an upper bound.

Comment: Yes. The equation was wrong as you pointed out. Assuming it as zero seems the easiest way. I was seeking statistical method to estimate weighted mean in spite of unknown values. Very thank you for your attention and reply.